# Delphi 2009 + Zeos + MySQL DBGrid displaying strings as (BYTES)

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-2009, zeos

I have some troubles with the Zeos library in Delphi 2009.
I have a MySQL database with utf8_bin encoding and when i'm trying to 
retrieve some strings from the DB and display it with a DBGrid the
DBGrid is displaying the word (BYTES) and not the actual string.

I tried to change some settings but in vain. After a lot of effort ,
i downloaded the Trial edition of the "DAC for MySQL" and oddly enough 
everything worked perfectly.

The program is a very simple program with a Zconnection, a Ztable,
a datasource and a DBGrid. The numbers are displaying correctly , only the strings have this problem. I tried different things but i have not idea 
what more i can do.

the MySQL version is    **5.6.24**

ZEOSlib   **7.1.4-stable**

If anyone have a suggestion please help me ! 
Thank you for your time (i'm sorry for my bad english )

Answer (score 0):

I've had quite the same problem with MySQL 5.6-23 And ZeosLib 7.1.4-stable with Delphi XE7.

My TZConnection is initialized with :

- ClientCodePage to latin1
- ControlsCodePage to cCP_UTF16
- Properties to

  - AutoEncodeStrings=ON
  - controls_cp=CP_UTF16
  - codepage=latin1
- protocol mysqld-5

My database was created with a default charset and collation (utf8/utf8_bin), and i had the same problem than yours, even with latin1/latin1_bin

Then I have changed the database by CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS MyDbName CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE **latin1_general_cs** and then all works fine

Hope it would be help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response , the problem in this solution is that i must change the collation from utf8_bin to latin1_general_cs , i prefer to avoid that and stick to utf8.